# How can I read numbers as integers while also reading in names as strings from a data file?

Tags: python, data-files

Here's the code I wrote to put the names and numbers into a file:

```
def main():
    num_players = int(input("How many players are there?"))
    golf = open("golf.txt", 'w')
    for i in range(num_players):
        player_name = str(input("What is the player's name?"))
        player_score = int(input("What is their golf score?"))
        golf.write(player_name + '\n')
        golf.write(str(player_score) + '\n')
    golf.close()

main()
```

and the output:

```
Palmer
120
Nicholas
118
Dalton
150
Woods
122
Player
124
```

In the following code, I am trying to compare the scores to see whose golf score is the best and the worst. I keep getting an error because `str` object cannot be interpreted as an integer. How can I fix this?

```py
def main():
    golf = open("golf.txt",'r')
    large = 125
    small = 119
    name=golf.readline()
    while name != '':
        for i in range(name):
            name = golf.readline()
            score = int(golf.readline())
            if score > large:
                large = score
                print(name,"is the worst at golf")
    while name != '':
        for i in range(name):
            name = golf.readline()
            score = int(golf.readline())
            if score < small:
                large = score
                print(name, "is the best at golf")

main()
```

Comment: `isnumeric()` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isnumeric-method/

Comment: it would make more sense to write the name and score on the same line separated with a comma: `golf.write(f"{player_name},{player_score}")` . This will make the process of importing the data easier.

Comment: The file consists of alternating string/int pairs. You, however, read one line before the loop, which means the rest of the file is alternating int/string pairs. But in the loop, you assume there are still alternating string/int pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal changes to OP code, with comments:

```py
with open("golf.txt") as golf: # make sure the file gets closed using with
    large = 0    # start small with largest
    small = 300  # start large with smallest

    # only one pass to read the file
    # compute small and large at the same time
    while name := golf.readline():  # while name is read... := is a newer feature of Python
        score = int(golf.readline()) # also read score
        if score > large:
            large = score
            worst = name.strip()  # make sure to save the worst name
        if score < small:
            small = score
            best = name.strip()   # and the best name

    # print results when done, not in the loop
    print(worst, "is the worst at golf")
    print(best, "is the best at golf")
```

Output:

```
Dalton is the worst at golf
Nicholas is the best at golf
```

Comment: Well explained! Neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def main():
    file_reader = open("golf.txt",'r')
    raw_data = file_reader.read().split('\n')
    file_reader.close()
    data = list(zip(raw_data[::2], [int(i) for i in raw_data[1::2]]))

    # search for smallest
    si = 0
    sv = data[si][1]
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if v[1] < sv:
            sv = v[1]
            si = i

    # search for biggest
    mi = si
    mv = data[mi][1]
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if v[1] > mv:
            mv = v[1]
            mi = i

    print(f'{data[si][0]} is the worst player.')
    print(f'{data[mi][0]} is the best player.')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Read()` the file and filter out any empty string. Use `zip()` to generate pair of `name` and `score` based on start index and step. Compare `large` and `small` to `int(score)` and then print the corresponding `name`.

```
def main():
    large = 125
    small = 119
    with open('golf.txt') as file:
        golf = file.read().splitlines()
        golf = [line for line in golf if line != '']
        for name, score in zip(golf[0::2], golf[1::2]):
            if int(score) > large:
                print(name, "is the worst at golf")
            elif int(score) < small:
                print(name, "is the best at golf")

main()

# Nicholas is the best at golf
# Dalton is the worst at golf
```